# How to open a telnet/ssh session in browsers on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-networking

I am creating a webpage which contains a lot of links to various devices and IP addresses. The requirement is such that when you click on any of the links in the webpage, it should open a telnet/ssh session to that device. I am able to do some registry changes and make the session open in a separate client like putty. But is there a way to open the session directly in the browser itself?

Thanks,
Guna

Comment: Sounds like you need a browser add-on to connect to putty. Does not sound like something that should be allowed (at least be default).

Comment: have a search for web based SSH

Answer (score 1):

You could host a client server side, e.g. using [Anyterm](http://anyterm.org/) or [Ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it's possible to implement an SSH client directly in JavaScript. Something like PuTTY but running directly in your browser. Unfortunately I've personally not seen such a tool and it would likely be quite slow (doing all SSH encryption within JavaScript).

I know some related projects which usually go a slightly different way. They use a JavaScript/AJAX based client in your browser to connect to a terminal proxy server:

- [WebShell](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mressl/webshell/)
- [Ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/)
- [Anyterm](http://anyterm.org/)

Alternatively you might be able to register specific protocol handlers on your systems which allow you to launch an existing terminal emulator like PuTTY. See [this site](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol) for some information on how to do this with Firefox.

After registering a protocol (e.g. console://) then you should be able to just insert links like `console://192.168.1.1` in your HTML documents in order to allow clients with properly registered console:// protocol handler to connect by launching the local PuTTY terminal emulator with correct parameters.